# How to name a point where we are "back to the initial route"?

Tags: routing, route, navigation

I have an initial route, that I leave (for instance in order to refuel). How to name the point where I'm back on the initial route?

Comment: I don't fully understand the purpose of this question. As in, how does this affect your routing? Or is it for documentation purposes? Are you looking for a literature-standard name, or just any name is fine?

Comment: @RobertoRibeiro Sorry, I acknowledge the lack of context. Yes, it was for code documentation purposes. I was wondering if there is a literature name for such a point / location, given a route. As suggested by Mesa below, "re-entry point" is meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe *"re-entry point"* would be a meaningful name.